The sharpest regularity result of elliptic PDEs: conditions on the variable coefficients
Let $\Omega  \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and bounded with a sufficiently smooth boundary. Let $L$ be a second order differential operator with variable coefficients, given by
$$Lu = \partial_i(a^{ij}\partial_ju) + b^i\partial_ku + c u.$$
For an arbitrary $f$, consider the boundary value problem posed in $\Omega$
$$
\begin{cases} Lu = f \\
\text{with boundary conditions}\\
\end{cases}
$$
The well-posedness of a weak solution and its regularity is extensively studied.
For instance, in Evan's PDEs we find for Dirichlet boundary conditions

THEOREM 5 (Higher boundary regularity). Let $m$ be a nonnegative
integer, and assume $ a^{i j}, b^i, c \in C^{m+1}(\bar{\Omega}) \quad(i,
> j=1, \ldots, n) $, and $ \partial \Omega \text { is } C^{m+2} $, and $ f \in H^m(\Omega) . $
Suppose that $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ is a weak solution of the boundary-value problem.
Then $$ u \in H^{m+2}(\Omega), $$ and we have the estimate $$
 \|u\|_{H^{m+2}(\Omega)} \leq C\left(\|f\|_{H^m(\Omega)}+\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\right),
$$ the constant $C$ depending only on $m, \Omega$ and the coefficients of
$L$.

In Grisvard's Elliptic Problems in Nonsmooth Domains we find Theorem 2.5.1.1 which gives the same result for more general boundary conditions but with $a^{ij} \in C^{m,1}(\overline{\Omega}), b^i \in C^{m,1}(\overline{\Omega})$ and $ \partial \Omega \text { is } C^{m+1,1}.$
My question is, what is the most relaxed conditions one can assume on the coefficients $a^{ij},b^i,c$, and $f$, and still get a similar regularity in Sobolev spaces as given in the previous theorems? The boundary can be assumed to be sufficiently smooth!
Providing references for further reading is much appreciated.

Have a look at the book by Krylov:Elliptic and parabolic equations in Sobolev spaces. If the operator is in non-divergence form the regularity theory requires less smoothness since you do not need to differentiate the top order coefficients.

If you are willing to fight through it, there is also the parabolic Ladyzhenskaja book, chapter III.§6 I think.

@Hannes I always wonder why such an important monograph is not re-released with modern typesetting.

You should note that the result 2.5.1.1 in Grisvard asks for a solution in $W^{2,p}$ already to get $W^{k+2,p}$ regularity, while the result in Evans only asks for a solution in $H^1_0 = W^{1,2}$.

For $m=0$ a very detailed study is given in the same book of Grisvard in Section 5.2. Basically, the diffusion $a^{ij}$ needs enough regularity so that you can use the technique of "freezing the coefficients" (Lipschitz is sufficient), while $b$ can be in $L^\infty$. Then there are geometric conditions on the coefficient $a^{ij}$ that are explained in detail in that section of Grisvard's book. In particular, with Theorem 5.2.2 you can compute the co-dimension that potentially prevents your solution from belonging to $W^{2,p}$. It's similar to working out corner singularities.
